# Как отобразить URL кириллицей

Tags: javascript, java, url

Подскажите как можно отобразить url кириллицей?
в js я генерирую url:

```
function redirect() {
let employeePhone = '+380980102030';
let id = 1321;
let employeeRole = 'ADMIN';
let name = 'Василий Фейк  Фейкович';
let dateTo = '2020-01-31'; 
let params ='phone=+'+employeePhone + '&id='+id + '&role='+ employeeRole +'&name=' + name + '&dateTo=' +dateTo;
       window.location = window.location.pathname + "/details?params=&"+params;
}
```

//localhost:8080/my/details?params=&phone=employeePhone&id=id&role=employeeRole&&name=name&dateTo=dateTo
код  в java:

```
@GetMapping("my/details")
    public String getStorePageDetails(Model model, QueryParam queryParam){
        try{
            model.addAllAttributes(getAtributes(queryParam));

        }catch(Exception e) {
            return "redirect:/my";
        }
        return "my/details/str";
    }

  private Map<String, ?> getAtributes(QueryParam param){
        Map<String, ? super Object> model = new HashMap<>();
        model.put("employeePhone", param.getPhone());
        model.put("employeeRole", param.getRole());
        model.put("espName", param.getName());
        model.put("dateTo", param.getDateTo());
        model.put("ourId", param.getId());
        return model;
    }
```

QueryParam обычный Pojo.
Проблема в том что параметры кириллицей 'Василий Фейк  Фейкович' в java приходят как null,то есть  param.getName()= null

Comment: Вам  надо энкодить значения параметров, вы не можете просто так передать русские символы. Если пропустить `Василий Фейк  Фейкович` через [`UrlEncode`](https://www.urlencoder.org/), получится `%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%20%20%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87`, см [JavaScript: encodeURI() function](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/functions/encodeURI-function.php)

Comment: Да, тогда параметры в java прийдут не null, но и в url будет %D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8..... а надо что было localhost:8080/my/details?params=&phone=+380980102030&id=1321&role=ADMIN&name=Василий-Фейк- Фейкович&dateTo=2020-01-31

Comment: Смотрим стандарт [URL](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) - `URLs are written only with the graphic printable characters of the US-ASCII coded character set.`, гуглим [US-ASCII](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html) и видим, что там только латинские буквы, кирилицы нет, то есть кирилица недопустима в URL.